# Find the solution $(1+2y)dx+(4-x^2)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> solve $(1+2y)dx+(4-x^2)dy=0$ using separation of variables

$$(1+2y)dx+(4-x^2)dy=0\implies (4-x^2)dy=-(1+2y)dx\implies \frac{dy}{(-1-2y)}=\frac{dx}{(4-x^2)}$$

Integrate the two sides:

$$\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2}\ln(-2y-1)&=\int \frac{dx}{4-x^2}\\
\\&\text{now,}\\
\int \frac{dx}{4-x^2}&=\int \frac{1}{2(2-x)}+\int \frac{1}{2(2+x)}\\
&=-\frac{\ln(2-x)}{2}+\frac{\ln(2+x)}{2}\\
\\&\text{now,}\\
-\frac{1}{2}\ln(-2y-1)&=-\frac{\ln(2-x)}{2}+\frac{\ln(2+x)}{2}+C\\
\implies\ln(-2y-1)&={\ln(2-x)}-{\ln(2+x)}-2C\\
\implies e^{\ln(-2y-1)}&=e^{{\ln(2-x)}-{\ln(2+x)}-2C}\\
\implies-2y\cdot e^{-1}&=e^{{\ln(2-x)}-{\ln(2+x)}-2C}\\
\implies y&=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot e^{{\ln(2-x)}-{\ln(2+x)}-2C+1}
\end{align}$$

Is the following correct? are the steps valid?

[the answer from wolfram is a bit different](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B2y)dx%3D(4-x%5E2)dy)

Comment: One thing to be careful of is that when you integrate to get the log, there should be an absolute value. The proper choice of the sign from this absolute value depends on the initial condition. In particular, this problem is well-posed if you take, say, $y(0)=0$, but in this case your derivation makes no sense. Similarly, the equation is well-posed if you put an initial condition at $x=3$, but again in this case your derivation makes no sense.

Comment: Another thing to be careful of is that this equation has a *stationary solution*. When you separate variables you remove this stationary solution from the problem essentially through division by zero. You need to check for this before separating variables.

Comment: You can usefully replace $-\ln{2-x}+\ln{2+x}$ by $\ln{\frac{2+x}{2-x}}$ (taking into account other comments)

Comment: A couple of observations: 1. You can simplify the result. 2.  You could shorten the beginning of your computation using the formula $$\int\frac{\mathrm d\mkern1mu x}{a^2-x^2}=\frac1{2a}\ln\biggl\lvert\frac{a+x}{a-x}\biggr\rvert.$$

Answer (score 3):

Not quite.  Note that

$$\int \frac{1}{-1-2y}\,dy=-\frac12 \log|2y+1| \tag 1$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{4-x^2}\,dx&=\int \left(\frac{1/4}{2-x}+\frac{1/4}{2+x}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac14 \log\left|\frac{x+2}{x-2}\right|+C \tag 2
\end{align}$$

Then, upon equating $(1)$ and $(2)$, we arrive at

$$-\frac12 \log|2y+1|=\frac14 \log\left|\frac{x+2}{x-2}\right|+C $$

from which we obtain

$$|2y+1|=A \sqrt{\frac{|x-2|}{|x+2|}}$$

Note that for $y>-1/2$, we find that

$$y=A' \sqrt{\frac{|x-2|}{|x+2|}} - \frac12$$

Comment: Why is it $\log|\frac{x+2}{x-2}|$ and $\log|\frac{x+2}{2-x}|$?

Comment: Recall that $-\log(x)=\log(1/x)$. Also recall that $|-x|=|x|$... ;-)) -Mark

Comment: I am not familiar with the square root, can I use $e$ to solve it?

Comment: You know that $\sqrt{x^2}=(x^2)^{1/2}=|x|$, yes?  And you know that $e^{\log(x)}=x$.  And you know that $\frac12 \log(x)=\log(x^{1/2})$.